# SectionIndexor in Android 3.0 Onwards

Tags: android, fastscroll, sectionindexer

I have an application in which i have implemented sectionIndexor to have alphabetical scrolling. This works fine with API level < 11. In higher versions i have a problem. The problem is that when i using fast scrolling thumb then i get to see the items properly. I have made that thumb(blue bar) always visible. But when i scroll slowly without using that thumb, that blue thumb icon disappears. When i touch the fast scroll Index thumb, i get the perfect results as shown below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBT4n.png

But when i scroll without using fastscrolling thumb(blue bar), The bluebar disappears and i can see only that line as shown below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgt8Z.png
Please guide me as to what i can do to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: I got to know that this is a framework bug. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33293
But i am not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question might be outdated for the OP, an answer may be interesting for others.

The problem looks like a missing/wrong implementation of the `getSectionForPosition` method of the `sectionIndexer` interface. I went a bit more into detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819394/section-indexer-get-section-for-position-returns-0/29318889#29318889) and also provided a sample implementation.